# Fitting and aligning two lists together in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to match up two lists made up of tuples (x,y,z). I need to fit them together based on the z-values, and remove any tuples containing z-values that are not common to both lists.

Input:

```
a = [(0,0,0),(3,4,1),(5,3,2),(1,2,3)]
b = [(0,1,1),(2,3,2),(3,4,4)]
```

Output:

```
a1 = [(3,4,1),(5,3,2)]
b1 = [(0,1,1),(2,3,2)]
```

z-values will be integers, not repeated.

Comment: What if there are repeated elements?

Comment: Have edited into OP. z-values will be integers, not repeated

Answer (score 4):

```
common_z = set([tup[2] for tup in a]).intersection([tup[2] for tup in b])
a_ = [tup for tup in a if tup[2] in common_z]
b_ = [tup for tup in b if tup[2] in common_z]

>>> a_
[(3, 4, 1), (5, 3, 2)]

>>> b_
[(0, 1, 1), (2, 3, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will partially satisfy your requirement and be a good starting point.
From here you can tweak it to return the cases of repetitions and how to order your stuff.

```
a= [(0,0,0),(3,4,1),(5,3,2),(1,2,3)]
b= [(0,1,1),(2,3,2),(3,4,4)]
a1=[] 
b1=[]
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i[2] == j[2]:
            a1.append(i)
            b1.append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it by using `set` as:

```
>>> a = [(0,0,0),(3,4,1),(5,3,2),(1,2,3)]
>>> b = [(0,1,1),(2,3,2),(3,4,4)]
# Intersection of z co-ordinates in 'a' and 'b' list
>>> z_ab = set(map(lambda x: x[2], a)) & set(map(lambda x: x[2], b))  

>>> new_a = filter(lambda x: x[2] in z_ab, a)
# new_a = [(3, 4, 1), (5, 3, 2)]
>>> new_b = filter(lambda x: x[2] in z_ab, b)
# new_b = [(0, 1, 1), (2, 3, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to this:

```
a = [(0,0,0),(3,4,1),(5,3,2),(1,2,3)]
b = [(0,1,1),(2,3,2),(3,4,4)]

a_dict = {z:[x,y] for x,y,z in a}
b_dict = {z:[x,y] for x,y,z in b}

a1=[]
b1=[]

for item in a_dict.keys():
    if item in b_dict.keys():
        a_dict[item].append(item)
        a1.append(tuple(a_dict[item]))
        b_dict[item].append(item)
        b1.append(tuple(b_dict[item]))

print(a1)
print(b1)
```